# NSUserDefaults will not save selections for multiple rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a button that toggles from selected to unselected. When the user changes it to selected I want it to save the settings. Upon re-entry to the tableview, all previously selected buttons should still be selected, but they aren't. With my code I'm able to set one row button, but if I select multiple rows only the last one stays selected. Here's what I've tried:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// code...

    if([cell.nameLbl.text isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"name"]]){
        [cell.likeBtn setSelected:YES];
    }else{
        [cell.likeBtn setSelected:NO];
    }
}
```

And in the delegate method for my TableViewCell

```
-(void)tableViewCell:(TableViewCell *)cell {
//code...
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    Car *car = self.carArray[indexPath.row];
    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userPreferences setObject:car.name forKey:@"name"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

What's missing to store multiple selected rows?

Comment: you have probably spotted you override the last value for the key `@"name"`, so literally you are storing the very last index only – not a _set_ of the selected indices, so I won't mention such obvious thing...

Comment: You really do not need to call `synchronize `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the value associated with the `@"name"` key every time. Instead, consider using an `NSArray` as the value, modifying it in the `select` and `deselect` delegate methods. Example:

```
// select
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userPreferences objectForKey:@"names"]];
[array addObject:car.name];
[userPreferences setObject:array forKey:@"names"];

// deselect
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userPreferences objectForKey:@"names"]];
[array removeObject:car.name];
[userPreferences setObject:array forKey:@"names"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Every time I hit: [array addObject:car.name]; I get an error [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I've tried changing car.name to a string. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but it stopped delivering the error. Works like a charm now.